# gcc does not warn "variable set but not used"

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, unused-variables

I have this MCVE which compiles without any warning:

```
auto foo() -> void
{
    int unused = 0;
    unused++;
}
```

For me I would expect `error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]`.

This MCVE compiles also without any warning:

```
auto foo() -> void
{
    int x;
    int unused;
    for ( ; x < 100; x++ )  unused++;
}
```

Here I would expect these two errors:

1. `error: variable ‘unused’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]`.
2. `error: ‘unused’ and ‘x’ are used uninitialized [-Werror=uninitialized]`

Adding `bar( unused );` above the `for` loop forces `gcc` to display the warning regarding using uninitialized variable.

Why is `gcc 4.9.3` **not** complaining in any of both MCVE's?

Compile command: `g++ -O3 -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

Compiling it with `-O1` I get this warning for the line with `for` : `error: ‘x’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`. All other optimization levels do not produce any warning.

Comment: Because it does not have to? Compilers are not static code analysers. It is possible that dead code elimination happens before rudimentary code analyser built into compiler has chance to see unused variable.

Comment: This would be a "feature request" to file with the Gnu folks.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yes, of course but in my eyes the warnings are not consistent.

Comment: In the 2nd case, optimisation levels above `O1` probably treat the whole body as UB and simply (as is their right) remove it - meaning there are no variables _left_ to warn about. There have been really interesting discussions on this elsewhere. Suffice it to say, with optimisation and UB, all bets are off. I'm not sure there's any easy way around this without radically changing how the analyser works, which probably isn't feasible by this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a 5 1/2 years old bug.

[See GCC Bugzilla – Bug 44677](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44677)

Answer (score 2):

The variables are not unused for the compiler. This warning is triggered only if you declare a local variable (and eventually initialize it) but then never use this variable in any statement.

So, in your examples, the variable `unused` is declared, initialized (in the first example) and used in the 2nd statement (here for reading and writing). The variable `x` is also declared and used (but not initialized).

In your second example, the compiler should show an "uninitialized" warning for the variable `x`. It may be an compiler bug if this warning is shown for `-O1` only?

Comment: Just an educated guess: with higher optimisation levels the compiler might see that the statement has no effect and does not produce any code at all. Thus, there is no "uninitialised" warning, because that variable is not used.

Comment: @Kane This MCVE is from a function with 320 lines. For other variables which were on another place in the function the warning has been shown. Anyway, I am wondering why this situation was preserved for these 3 lines of code. For me it looks like a `gcc 4.9.3` "bug".

Comment: @Kane this is possible, but in my opinion, the warnings should be generated before the optimization phase (the warnings should help the developer to find potential bugs and the optimizer should not try to hide them). So i think it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @ul90 Just checked the assembly code (gcc 5.3.1): it completely removes the loop if compiled with `-02` or `-03`. So the compiler technically is correct: the variable is not used uninitialised.

Comment: @Kane but the warnings are not shown consistently. As I mentioned before for other variables the warning are shown. I consider it as a bug. Note: It comes from a 320 lines function...